# Azure PostgreSQL suddenly uses all storage

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-postgresql

Yesterday, an 'Azure Database for PostgreSQL server' database I have been appending to continually suddenly increased its rate of growth and used up all the storage, and the script reported errors as the connection became read-only.
[image: plot of azure storage %]

The queries for the database size on disk don't add up to anything like 18GB

```
    select pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('database_alpha')) => '80 MB'
    select pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('database_beta')) => '458 MB'
    select pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('postgres')) => '8645 kB'
```

If it's not my databases, what could be using the storage and how do I prevent it happening in future?

Looking at the logs, around 5pm there start to be a lot of entries similar to:

```
2018-08-26 15:52:39 UTC-5b819a84.45490-WARNING:  archiving write-ahead log file "000000010000004E000000DA" failed too many times, will try again later
2018-08-26 15:52:49 UTC-5b819a84.45490-WARNING:  archiving write-ahead log file "000000010000004E000000DA" failed too many times, will try again later
2018-08-26 15:52:56 UTC-5b819a84.45490-WARNING:  archiving write-ahead log file "000000010000004E000000DA" failed too many times, will try again later
2018-08-26 15:53:00 UTC-5b819a84.45490-WARNING:  archiving write-ahead log file "000000010000004E000000DA" failed too many times, will try again later
2018-08-26 15:53:04 UTC-5b819a84.45490-WARNING:  archiving write-ahead log file "000000010000004E000000DA" failed too many times, will try again later
2018-08-26 15:53:08 UTC-5b819a84.45490-WARNING:  archiving write-ahead log file "000000010000004E000000DA" failed too many times, will try again later
2018-08-26 15:53:11 UTC-5b819a84.45490-WARNING:  archiving write-ahead log file "000000010000004E000000DA" failed too many times, will try again later
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing a hardware failure prevented it writing the WAL and that was taking the space, it seems to have recovered now:

[image]